# Half of the video player screen goes crazy when playing any online or local video

Tags: windows-10, video, graphics-card, display

I searched around and could not find any similar issue online. Please let me know if this is not the right place.

I'm on Windows 10 pro 64 bit OS, Sony VAIO Pro 13 laptop with Intel Core i7-4500U CPU, 8GB RAM, Intel HD Graphic adapter. (Every driver is updated to the most recent version)

So whenever I played a video, no matter it's from YouTube or from a local video player. The screen will become like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qy91.jpg). This only happens recently, it was all good before.

So only the right half of the 'video section' goes crazy, all other parts of the display remains intact. This happens no matter with an external display or without.

Please help, any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also have a Vaio laptop and have had the same problem for maybe the last 6-9 months. I don't have a definite answer, but from some googling I've done it seems like it maybe is an issue with upgrading to Windows 10. I haven't managed to fix mine yet but here are some links that offer some insight/potential solutions:

https://community.sony.com/t5/VAIO-Windows-10/Video-distorted-after-Windows-10-Upgrade/td-p/520615

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/windows-10-video-playback-problems/55035a6a-1f06-40e7-a944-3bd32aadb9eb?auth=1

Comment: Thanks! Specifically the answer [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-movies/videos-distorted-after-windows-10-upgrade/c876cbd2-9b5c-4135-aa57-d7e33c6f9147?auth=1) solved my problem.